# How to make a stepwise regression without NA cells being omitted?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, na

I'm doing a stepwise regression to determine the significance of my parameters. When I run the following code, I get the error

> Warning message: In add1.lm(fit, scope$add, scale = scale, trace = trace, k = k,  :
> using the 6/384 rows from a combined fit.

```
echo_data = read.csv("C:PLACEHOLDER_PATHWAY", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)

nothing <- lm(Gap ~ 1, data = echo_data)

model <- lm(Gap ~ ., data = echo_data, na.action = "na.exclude")

stepwiseregression <- step(object = nothing, scope = list(lower = formula(nothing), upper = formula(model), direction = "forward"))

summary(stepwiseregression)
```

There are many fields that are NA, but since I have ~70 columns and just under 400 rows this is bound to happen. I've tried omitting the NA cells with both na.omit and na.exclude as echo_data<-na.omit(echo_data) right after creating the object, but then I get the error "attempting model selection on an essentially perfect fit is nonsense", which I suppose occurs as there are too few data points.

How do I make a stepwise regression based on the many data points I do have, without almost 400 rows being omitted?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the entire program, there is no more code to add.

Comment: If possible post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including minimal data to reproduce the problem.